# Is there any reason why joining two views over quadruples their combined run times

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimization

I have 2 views that are selecting large datasets from an external source.
They aren't doing any calculations or aggregations, just a long select  statement.

I am using an

```sql
INNER JOIN
```

to link the two views based on a GUID.

The individual selections from each view are as follows.

view1, 3:08 Run time, 174,842 Records retrieved

view2, 0:02 Run Time, 93,493 Records retrieved

When I Join them, I get the following

Join, 14:32 Run Time, 177,753 records retrieved

So far, I've tried

```sql
LEFT JOIN 
RIGHT JOIN 
INNER JOIN
JOIN
```

I've tried joining view1 to view2 vs joining view2 to view1.
I've tried calling one view then selecting from that while joining to the other view.

Nothing seems to impact it.

SQL below for reference

```sql
SELECT
    v1.guid, 
    CONVERT(DATE, v1.CreatedOn) AS CreatedOn,
    field1, 
    field2, 
    field3,
    field4,
    field5
FROM
    View1 v1
    INNER JOIN View2 V2 ON v1.guid = v2.guid
WHERE
    field6 = 'value'
```

(obligatory those aren't the actual field names)

I'm getting the expected result, its just taking way too long for its purpose.

Any help optimising would be appreciated

Comment: Your two options would appear to be compiler hints or storing the results in temporary tables.  It might also be possible to optimize the queries using indexes, but that requires much more knowledge about the views.

Comment: The engine optimizes a query containing views as a whole by expanding the view definitions as though they were subqueries; it does not "run" the views and then combine the results, so the result is not a linear combination. For remote queries especially, the optimizer can easily fail to get a good execution plan and effectively end up pumping over an entire table before filtering, instead of remoting the join. You'll need to dig in and compare execution plans for the various queries. One obvious workaround is to explicitly select intermediate results in temp tables before joining.

Comment: If the queries used in those views are really simple, then it might be worth it to base your query directly on the tables used in those views.  The optimizer would have an easier time to find the best execution plan. But you mentioned that they get data from an external datasource.  So the use of temp tables with the right indexes might be better here.

Comment: Yeah i saw a lot of people talking about indexes while looking for a solution but i didn't create either view and i don't really know them well enough to start trying to apply indexes

Comment: This statement is going to be creating a view once it can run fairly quickly so i cant use temp tables, i did consider it but its not something that is applicable

Comment: You're wanting to create a new view on top of two other views? The query optimizer is only so smart and will eventually default to dumb plans as you increase the view depth. Actually, what's the likelihood of your two views already containing other views?

Comment: No chance, the two views are running massive select statements from external tables that I dont have access to edit

Comment: AlwaysLearning thanks for the help! I went into the two big select views and found the table name, now im just selecting out the fields i need directly. I'll post an updated runtime once i've finished

Comment: Wooo 33 seconds!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
SELECT *
INTO #view1
FROM view1

SELECT *
INTO #view2
FROM view2

SELECT
    v1.guid, 
    CONVERT(DATE, v1.CreatedOn) AS CreatedOn,
    field1, 
    field2, 
    field3,
    field4,
    field5
FROM #View1 v1
INNER JOIN #View2 V2 
    ON v1.guid = v2.guid
WHERE
    field6 = 'value'
```

The first two statements materialized the view data in temporary tables. If the engine is not able to build good execution plan in your original query, the above should help.

If the above is not helping, try to defined the temporary tables the better way defining primary keys. Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #view1
(
    guid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER PRIMARY KEY
    ....
)

INSERT INTO #view1
SELECT *
FROM view1
```

So, in this way the data should be ordered by `GUID` and in theory we should get faster join.

The above can lead to better performance but we have a bigger issue here - you are joining by `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` - I know you may see people using this as primary key, but you will finding joining by `int` or `bigint` faster. If you need such `guid` column in order not to expose internal IDs in your application or something else, this does not not mean you can't have integer column to perform the joins in the SQL.

Also, if you are not able to store the data in the view in temporary tables, you can check how indexed views are created and if you can - store the data that is needed only (apply filtering criteria in advance) - for example:

```
INSERT INTO #view1
SELECT *
FROM view1
WHERE field6 = 'value'
```

So, now the table has fewer rows, right?

Comment: `select *` is evil. Only select the columns you need.

Comment: I can't use temp tables and I didn't build the original views so I don't really know them, or SQL in general, well enough to start indexing them

Comment: @Rob_O just do as the answer says :) follow the necessary steps and you'll be fine

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Yes, it is best to materialized only the rows and the columns you need.

Comment: @Rob_O Try this in order to find what's the issue. Sometimes people are using views with a lot of columns returned and tables joined only to select part of the data - you may end up creating simplified versions of the views.

Comment: @gotqn This, combined with some help from Alwayslearning has cut the run time down to 33 seconds! Thank you both

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the answer was don't select 100+ columns into a view then select 1 column out of it! who would've thought it